# Issue: Confusing: Index must be a positive integer or logical

Tags: matlab

I've got such a problem using MATLAB:

I wrote this function:

```
function E = f(x, lamda)

E = 1 - exp(-lamda * x);

end
```

When I write: `Prob = f(1000, lamda);` where `lamda =  3.4274e-004`
I get this error:

```
??? Attempted to access f(1000,0.000341565); index must be a positive integer or logical.
```

I understand that it requires a positive integer, but why ? I need `lamda` to be real. What's the problem here ? Can you, please, tell me where I'm wrong?

Comment: check if you have a variable called `f` in your workspace. Your error message indicates that you're trying to access the the 1000th row and 0.000341565th column of matrix f.

Comment: So it might be that I defined two variables using f , yes?

Comment: You might have defined one variable named `f` and another function `f`.

Comment: @TamásSzabó Yes, you are right. Can you, please post your answer, for me to accept ?

Comment: In your post you define the _function_ `E = f(x,lambda)`. If you, at the same time, have a _variable_ in your workspace called `f`, than you're trying to access elements of that variable

Comment: @Yes, I've corrected this, and it was really this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a function `f` and a variable `f` declared at the same time.  Do `clear f;` then try your code again.  What's happening here is that the variable declaration takes precedence over your function and so doing `f` would try and access the variable `f` first.

If you're using `f` as a variable somewhere and can't change this, then **rename** your function to be something other than `f`... perhaps... `comp` or something.  Once you do this, make sure you change your file name so that it's called `comp.m`, then do:

```
Prob = comp(1000, lamda);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error message indicates that there is a variable called `f` in your workspace and matlab thinks you are trying to access its elements. Remove the variable `f` with `clear('f')` or rename the function to something else and you should be fine.